# How to create a scroll bar (up-down) in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, list, navigation

I need to create a scroll bar in a SharePoint list so I can keep the toolbar visible when scrolling down the page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this [Example](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-jquery-scrolling-view-with.html)

Comment: Whilst I'm not discouraging linking to external resources, could you expand your answer with a summary of what's described on that blog entry. This means that if the link goes dead we won't all be scratching our heads wondering what was there :)  Thanks.